# Stop Carp background location when close app

Tags: flutter

I'm using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/carp_background_location, but when I close the app, the location service continues, and I don't wanna that.

I already tryed to calling the stop function on detached, observing the lifecycle, but doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.